# Async loading of some generated Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, asynchronous, deferred-loading

I work for a small company that isn't flexible in making changes on using a heavy themed webpage on Wordpress for their own reasons. They are also using a load of plugins, and it takes more than 10 seconds to load. So, I thought I should give it a try and check the generated homepage source code, after I ran the analysis that tells me that js is just a disaster.
***The theme they had chosen was Unero,*** because it works with woocommerce I suppose. The website is a small e-shop along with a blog, nothing too fancy really, we use yoast SEO too, but that might be irrelevant.
I realized that there is a load of js scripts running here and there.
I read that you can set everything run with async set true.

A also read that this can cause things to break between scripts, due to undefined variables and other problems I suppose. Please note that I am kinda new to js technologies and I might not know what I really should be asking, or searching for. I do my best to explain what I need to happen though.

1. Is there a way you can override ( or overload, what is the term
   here?)**some** js on footer, after being defined on their positon
   (in HEAD and in BODY),setting it to async mode, by using a snippet
   on footer? Will this actually work?
2. I do not want to involve any plugin general solutions, because I am
   afraid they will break stuff as mentioned above. Correct me if I am
   wrong and please suggest me something. Except if the solution IS to make a custom plugin, where I will have full control I guess.
3. I am open on ANY suggestions, as long as it won't break the site.

I am asking here and not on Wordpress Developement or any other Stack Exchange forum, because I am looking for a solution done by hand, along with an explaination why it will work. I am a code by hand guy really, and I am not afraid to dive deeper on something, if things are gonna be done right.

Comment: Not certain what the issue is. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Better loading times for homepage to achieve better SEO scores, without breaking anything.

Comment: _"Better loading times for homepage to acheve better SEO scores"_ How can and will that result be objectively determined by applying prospective suggestions that could be included in one or more answers to your question? _"I work for a small company that isn't flexible in making changes"_ How will you manage to any suggestions included in answers implemented? How will users here know that "SEO" has "improved"?

Comment: Well their website, is using a lot of js, that isn't asynced or deferred. I am not sure how to handle this really, since I don't know how to approach the problematic code. They want changes, but they don't want to change the theme (which is really part of the problem I suppose). Yes point taken, it's not MY problem, it's their prolbem, but if nobody does something, it won't get fixed and I am the kind of a guy that does his best to work things out.

Comment: You mentioned that management is not _"flexible"_ relevant to _"making changes"_. How will you get any suggested changes which could be included in an answer implemented?

Comment: Updated my comment above your last one, please take a look again and thanks for caring.

Comment: The "problem" is not clear. Unless you simply mean rearranging the existing code to achieve a different result? How is any solution objectively measurable? Within the scope of this question how exactly is "SEO" measured?

Comment: Well I was thinking I could re arrange stuff ad-hoc using a piece of code. Meaning whatever plugin is added or removed, I could dynamically see what js code exists and handle it accordingly. But it seems there is no easy solution for this. I must study and create a custom plugin to handle the mess they got, or convince them to change attitude on using another theme.

Comment: Again, how is "SEO" objectively measured?  How will you know when "SEO" is "better"? That would be the first item to clearly define. Else, how can any metrics be objectively evaluated? If you are using service X to determine "SEO" that is a single definition. If service X, service Y, and your own estimation of load times of the page is used, that all should be clear.

Comment: Well I might run again an insight https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=en  
hat is how I apporached the problem at first time. And it will take some time to see results I suppose, maybe a recrawl of sitemap with fixes updated. And maybe by looking what Google gives as result on firts few pages again.

Comment: Also, "SEO" is not purely about the load time of an HTML `document`. The "SE" can be paid directly to "Optimize" the result displayed to users who use their service. Other techniques can be used to "optimize" the _search engine_ displaying the site in the results. If the actual technical issue is what you are interested in, then yes, address the code as well. While page load time might be important to some it is not the only metric or means to address "SEO", or, plainly, being listed in the top portion of returned results of a search for X.

Comment: True. First loading time is above 10 seconds. That is the problem. Forget about SEO, it just affects it too, the main fact is that nobody waits 10 seconds for a homepage to load today. That is why I also said " we use yoast SEO too, but that might be irrelevant." I firstly care for User Experience and so does google when ranks a page.

Comment: Why does it take 10 seconds to load the page? What is the content rendered? Not sure what yoast is supposed to do. Roll own "SEO" by hand, here.

Comment: Google Insights shows that the delay is caused by many JS scripts that wait one another.

Comment: What do the scripts do that is essential to the rendering of the HTML `document`? Have you tried using a `ServiceWorker` or dedicated `Worker` to request scripts and/or media as needed?

Comment: Here are some of the most delaying results. It is mostly Js and CSS files that need to load:
jquery-2.10.2.css
wp-includes-js-jquery-jquery-1.12.4.js
wp-content-plugins-revslider-public-assets-js-jquery.them….js
wp-conten….11.2.js
wp-content-themes-unero-style-20170106.css

Comment: Why do individuals visit the site? What is the first activity that a user performs when visiting the site? Why is jQuery necessary?

Comment: Either get info about products the company sells, and maybe add stuff to cart and do a checkout.

Comment: I got NO IDEA why Jquery is needed. Probably because of the theme....

Comment: The simplest approach would be to create a basic HTML document which describes why the site exists. While the user is consuming that information the e-commerce portion of the site can be loaded and _linked_ to at the main HTML `document`. If jQuery is not necessary, do not use jQuery.

Comment: Yes makes sense. It would be also nice to convince them to get rid of that heavy theme, to save them a lot of trouble. But since they ask for alternatives, I will suggest that and maybe even give them a link to our conversation. Really thanks for your time, I do appreciate it, hopefully I will try things on Monday and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way you can override ( or overload, what is the term
>   here?)some js on footer, after being defined on their positon (in HEAD
>   and in BODY),setting it to async mode, by using a snippet on footer?
>   Will this actually work?

Answer: Yes, its possible but that could also happen with sync code. If plugin A is doing something like `$('title').text('Title from A')` and then the next plugin does `$('title').text('Title from B')`then its gonna get overridden, doesn't matter if its sync or async.

> I do not want to involve any plugin general solutions, because I am
>   afraid they will break stuff as mentioned above. Correct me if I am
>   wrong and please suggest me something.

Answer: I am not sure what you want to do. What is your goal with this site? Do you want to untangle the mess of the plugins? That can be difficult since you have little control over the plugins and their mechanismm.

> I am open on ANY suggestions, as long as it won't break the site.

Answer: One way would be to disable them one by one to see cause and effect and try to clean out that way. Another solution would to switch to more simple solution like Shopify and the third to creaate a custom solution that you have more control over.

Its quite an open question, so its kinda of hard to give a concrete answer or solution to your problem.

Comment: I see.Very unfortunate really, not for me, but for the company. They will have to change their point of view on changing theme or WAIT for me to study a few things and actually go for a custom solution, a custom plugin maybe,  to fix the mess. I mean I am embarrassed enough to waste tech experts time on asking how to approach a problem that can in fact be solved by changing a few stuff here and there and set things up from scratch on just an SSL and some credentials.